# Evaluate $\int_{-1}^1 \frac {1}{\sqrt{|x|}} \text{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, absolute-value

I need some help to solve this integral with absolute value. I'm not sure how to do these types of integrals.

> $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac {1}{\sqrt{|x|}} \text{d}x$$

Thank you

Comment: This function is symmetric about the $y$ axis, so $\int_{-1}^1 \frac {1}{\sqrt{|x|}} dx=2\cdot \int_{0}^1 \frac {1}{\sqrt{|x|}} dx=2\cdot\int_{0}^1 \frac {1}{\sqrt{x}} dx$.

Comment: Of course, i see it now. Thank you! One question though, can i do that in all cases where there are symmetry or only when f(x) converges? Hope you understand my question

Comment: @KimR You can only use this if $\int f(x)$ converges. Cf $\int_{-1}^1 \frac1x \ne 0$ is undefined, although the function is point symmetric about $0$, so $\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon} \frac1x + \int_{\epsilon}^1 \frac1x = 0$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mike Earnest's hint about the symmetrical property of this particular question works, but I will like to present another method/hint on dealing with modulus functions that still works even when dealing with asymmetrical limits.

It involves splitting up the modulus into cases by restricting the domain.

$$ |f(x))| =
\begin{cases}
f(x) & \textrm{if } f(x) \geq 0 \\
-f(x) & \textrm{if } f(x) < 0 
\end{cases}$$
In particular,
$$ |x| =
\begin{cases}
x & \textrm{if } x \geq 0 \\
-x & \textrm{if } x < 0 
\end{cases}$$
Hence, our required integral can be decomposed into
\begin{equation} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}} \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-1}^0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{-x}} \mathrm{d}x + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \mathrm{d}x \end{equation}

As AlexR points out, even though the function isn't defined for $x=0$, the integrals still work by considering limits for some small $\epsilon$. In particular, both integrals on the right exist, so the integral for the question exists and the equality is valid.